# getting Rss feed in ionic 2 issues

Tags: javascript, android, html, angularjs, ionic2

please I'm having some trouble while trying to parse rss feed using Ionic Framework 2. When I run the code it returns an error: *Cannot read property 'title' of undefined*. Could you help me?

The project github repository.

https://github.com/edogbosunny/TestApp

### reddits-service.ts

```
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    /*
      Generated class for the RedditService provider.

      See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
      for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
    */
    @Injectable()
    export class RedditService {
    baseUrl: any;
      constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.http=http;
        this.baseUrl = 'http://naijavibz.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json';
        console.log('Hello RedditService Provider');
      }
    getPost(){
      return this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
      .map(res => res.json());
    }
    }
```

reddits.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
        import {RedditService} from '../../providers/reddit-service';
        import {DetailsPage} from '../details/details' ;

        /*
          Generated class for the Reddits page.

          See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
          Ionic pages and navigation.
        */
        @Component({
          selector: 'page-reddits',
          templateUrl: 'reddits.html'
        })
        export class RedditsPage {
        items:any;
        feeds:any;
        posts:any;
          constructor(public redditservice:RedditService, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

          }
        ngOnInit(){
          this.getPost();
        }
        getPost(){
          this.redditservice.getPost().subscribe(response =>{
            console.log(response);
            this.items = response.feed.entry;
          })
        }
        viewItem(item){
          this.navCtrl.push(DetailsPage,{
            item:item
          });
        }
          ionViewDidLoad() {
            console.log('ionViewDidLoad RedditsPage');
          }

        }
```

reddits.html

```
          See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
          Ionic pages and navigation.
        -->
        <ion-header>

          <ion-navbar>
            <ion-title>NaijaVibz</ion-title>
          </ion-navbar>

        </ion-header>

        <ion-content padding>
        <ion-list >
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        <h2>{{item.entry.title}}</h2>

        </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
```

Log from console

```
    Objectencoding: "UTF-8"feed: Objectauthor: Array[1]category:
 Array[6]entry:
 Array[25]generator: 
Objectid: Objectlink:
 Array[5]openSearch$itemsPerPage:
 ObjectopenSearch$startIndex: 
ObjectopenSearch$totalResults:
 Objectsubtitle: Objecttitle: 
Objectupdated: Objectxmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"xmlns$blogger: "http://schemas.google.com/blogger/2008"xmlns$gd: "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005"xmlns$georss: "http://www.georss.org/georss"xmlns$openSearch: "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/"xmlns$thr: "http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0"__proto__: Objectversion: "1.0"__proto__: Object
    error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Error in ./RedditsPage class RedditsPage - inline template:34:4 caused by: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:47
    IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ ionic-error-handler.js:56
    next @ application_ref.js:272
    schedulerFn @ async.js:82
    SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
    SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
    Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
    Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
    Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
    EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
    NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
    onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
    t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3
    e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
    invoke @ polyfills.js:3

    **error_handler.js:49 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined**

    ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:49
    IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ ionic-error-handler.js:56
    next @ application_ref.js:272
    schedulerFn @ async.js:82
    SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
    SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
    Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
    Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
    Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
    EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
    NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
    onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
    t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3
    e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
    invoke @ polyfills.js:3
    error_handler.js:52 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
    ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:52
    IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ ionic-error-handler.js:56
    next @ application_ref.js:272
    schedulerFn @ async.js:82
    SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
    SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
    Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
    Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
    Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
    EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
    NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
    onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
    t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3
    e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
    invoke @ polyfills.js:3
    error_handler.js:53 TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
        at View_RedditsPage1.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/RedditsPage/component.ngfactory.js:234)
        at View_RedditsPage1.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:288)
        at View_RedditsPage1.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:381)
        at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (view_container.js:45)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_RedditsPage0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/RedditsPage/component.ngfactory.js:120)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:288)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:381)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_RedditsPage_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/RedditsPage/host.ngfactory.js:29)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:288)
        at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:381)
    ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:53
    IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ ionic-error-handler.js:56
    next @ application_ref.js:272
    schedulerFn @ async.js:82
    SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
    SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
    Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
    Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
    Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
    EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
    NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
    onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
    t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3
    e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
    invoke @ polyfills.js:3
    error_handler.js:56 ERROR CONTEXT:
    ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:56
    IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ ionic-error-handler.js:56
    next @ application_ref.js:272
    schedulerFn @ async.js:82
    SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
    SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
    Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
    Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
    Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
    EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
    NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
    onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
    t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3
    e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
    invoke @ polyfills.js:3
    error_handler.js:57 DebugContext {_view: View_RedditsPage1, _nodeIndex: 3, _tplRow: 34, _tplCol: 4}
    ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:57
    IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ ionic-error-handler.js:56
    next @ application_ref.js:272
    schedulerFn @ async.js:82
    SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
    SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
    Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
    Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
    Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
    EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
    NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
    onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
    t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3
    e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
    invoke @ polyfills.js:3
```

Comment: did you log the data.. maybe entry is null within item

Comment: The data is not null. It is logged. I can see what it returns but when I try navigating to it it says user undefined.

Comment: its definitely a parsing issue of the object.. people can tell you if you post the log of the object

Comment: @suraj please find the log files attached now with the code thanks

Comment: Well I cant really tell object structure here.. try `console.log(JSON.stringify(items,undefined,2))`

Comment: i tried it but it did not work i have also attached a github repo of the app please.

Comment: either you are not traversing object right or there is a null somewer.. try the url with a rest client like postman..

Comment: @surat pls would really appreciate if you take a look at the repo on git hub.you probably might see somthing am missing.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already set items array as `response.feed.entity` here:

```
this.items = response.feed.entry;
```

Unless the json has nested entity values, your html should have:

```
  <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion and the result that was displayes was [object] [Object]

Comment: am not sure beyond this..you may have to debug

Comment: Wow...ok can u please take a look at the ripo at your spare time please

Comment: @ Suraj i think there is a workaround using this blogger url cause i just applier the same code using the reddit api and it worked. Thanks